# select most matched rows at first in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, sorting

my project is running on laravel 5.4, mysql 5.7

I have 4 tables

```
recipes             (id, name)
ingredient_recipe   (id, recipe_id, ingredient_id, amount)
ingredients         (id, name, cat_id)
ingredient_category (id, name)
```

`recipes` and `ingredients` have `many to many relations` through `ingredient_recipe` table. each recipe can have many ingredients. each ingredient has its category `cat_id` which references to `id` in `ingredient_category` table.

I need to select all recipes which ingredients' categories ids equals the requested values, and put the most matched values at top.
for example requested ingredient categories ids are `[23,56,76,102,11]`.
lets say recipe `foo` have ingredients which categories matched `23,56,76`, `bar` matched `23,56` and `baz` matched `23`. they should be ordered - `foo, bar, baz`. how can I order them in this way?

here's my sql code

```
 --select recipes
SELECT * from recipes where exists
    --select recipe's ingredients
   (select `ingredients`.`id` 
    from `ingredients` 
    inner join 
       `ingredient_recipe` on `ingredients`.`id` = 
       `ingredient_recipe`.`ingredient_id` where `recipes`.`id` = 
       `ingredient_recipe`.`recipe_id` 
    and exists 
      --select ingredient categories, where id .. 
     (select `ingredient_category`.`id` 
      from `ingredient_category` 
      where `ingredients`.`cat_id` = `ingredient_category`.`id` 
      and `id` IN (23,56,76,102,11)))
```

but this code doesn't 'put' mostly matched recipes at top. I know I can do select like in this example and then filter them, but is there way to do in in sql?

Comment: Note that unless you can add a given ingredient to the same recipe twice, id in your second table serves no purpose

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thank you for reply, can you please be more specific why there's no purpose? recipes can have many ingredients

Comment: Yes but recipes generally only use each ingredient once

Comment: ok, how it should be then?

Comment: I would form a composite PRIMARY KEY on two of the remaining 3 columns. Also, in addition to amount, I think you should also have unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the recipe table to the ingredient table via the junction table `ingredient_recipe`, and then aggregate by recipe.  For each recipe, we can count the number of ingredients which map your list, and we can order the result set with the higher matches appearing first.

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.cat_id IN (23, 56, 76, 102, 11) THEN 1 END) AS match_cnt 
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN ingredient_recipe ir
    ON r.id = ir.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i
    ON ir.ingredient_id = i.id
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY match_cnt DESC;
```

We could also add a `HAVING` clause, e.g. to filter off recipes which do not meet a minimum number of matching ingredients.  We could also a `LIMIT` clause to limit the total number of matches.

Comment: @Strawberry `SUM` would take up more space and might not fit on a single line.  We can't have that, now can we? :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY and a left join to the categories table to get a count of the number of categories, then sort on that count.

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`,
    a.`name`,
    c.`id`.
    c.`name`,
    count(d.`id`) as `numcategories`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.`name`)
FROM `recipes` a
JOIN `ingredient_recipe` b
ON a.`id` = b.`recipe_id`
JOIN `ingredients` c
ON b.`ingredient_id` = c.`id`
LEFT JOIN `ingredient_category` d
ON c.`cat_id` = d.`id`
GROUP BY a.`name`,c.`name`
ORDER BY count(d.`id`) DESC, a.`name`,c.`name`
```